# Method inefficiency

Tags: java, big-o

This is from code fights. The method works but is apparently taking too long for large inputs. Can someone please explain what is inefficient about this solution?

Question:
Given an array of integers, write a function that determines whether the array contains any duplicates. Your function should return true if any element appears at least twice in the array, and it should return false if every element is distinct.

Example

For a = [1, 2, 3, 1], the output should be
containsDuplicates(a) = true.

There are two 1s in the given array.

Solution:

```
    static boolean containsDuplicates(int[] a) {
    boolean elementRepeat = false;
    for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < a.length; loop1++){
        for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < a.length; loop2++){
            if (a[loop1] == a[loop2] && loop1!=loop2){                   
                elementRepeat = true;
                return elementRepeat;
            }
        }
    }

    return elementRepeat;
}
```

Comment: You have a nested loop - so it is `O(n^2)`

Comment: This is a quadratic function and will not scale.

Comment: You may want to read about `HashSet`.

Comment: There is also a simple way to make your original algorithm up to 2 times faster (but still O(n²)). If you already know that say a[1] is not equal to a[4], do you have to compare a[4] to a[1]?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, very helpful. Thanks for the downvotes lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that @Henry did a very good sugestion.

This is an example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arrayInt = {1, 2, 3, 1};

        Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        boolean hasDuplicates = false;

        for (Integer integerNumber : arrayInt) {
            if (!integers.add(integerNumber)) {
                hasDuplicates = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Contains duplicates? " + hasDuplicates);
    }

}
```

And it will print:

> Contains duplicates? true

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by storing the array in `Set` and then comparing the length of the array and set. Here is how:

```
 static boolean containsDuplicates(int[] array) {
    HashSet<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(integers::add);
    array.length == integers.size();
 }
```

Comment: While the code is shorter this is on average most likely slower than the approach of Denis Jr. You cannot stop early as soon as a duplicate is found.

Comment: Yes @Henry, you are right. It has `O(n)` complexity.